# Splice result if timed event

Tags: javascript, array-splice

I would like to be able to take out the result of a timed event, but I am not sure how to find the index for it. The problem is that I am choosing an item from the array by time, but by index number, so I need to be able to get the result after the timer has run.

It will be along the lines of

```
mixedgroup1.splice(i, 1);
```

where i is the index number of the final result, but I cannot tell how to get it.

Any ideas?

Here is the JS code:

```
var basket = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'durian', 'eggplant', 'fig', 'grapes', 'huckleberry', 'kiwi', 'lemon', 'mango'];

 function randOrd(){
return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); } 

 mixedBasket = basket.sort( randOrd ); //randomize the array

 var i = 0;  // the index of the current item to show


 function showBasket(){
 fruitDisplay = setInterval(function() {            
    document
        .getElementById('fruit')
        .innerHTML = mixedBasket[i++];    // get the item and increment
    if (i == mixedBasket.length) i = 0;   // reset to first element if you've reached the end
 }, 70);  //speed to display items

 var endFruitDisplay = setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval(fruitDisplay); }, 3600); 
 //stop display after x milliseconds
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<html>

<head></head>
<body>


<center>
   <h1> <span id="fruit"></span><p></h1>
 <script> var fruitSound = new Audio(); 
        fruitSound.src = "boardfill.mp3"; 

    function showFruitwithSound()
    { 
    fruitSound.play(); // Play button sound now 
    showBasket()
    } 

 </script>

<button onclick="showFruitwithSound()">Choose Fruit</button>

</center> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="Fruitpicker3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to get the index of the final result:

```
mixedBasket.indexOf(document.getElementById('fruit').innerHTML);
```

Add this here:

```
var endFruitDisplay = setTimeout(function( ) { 
        clearInterval(fruitDisplay); 
        var index = mixedBasket.indexOf(document.getElementById('fruit').innerHTML); 

        //do splice and stuff

        document.getElementById("indexnum").innerHTML = index;    
    }, 3600);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get any output from this, not even -1. I have rewritten the html as:

Comment: This works well, up until the final few items. I cut it down to five fruits, to see how it would behave, and these are the results:

Comment: mixedBasket: date, durian, cherry, apple, banana
Run 1: Returns “banana,” shows Index 4. (Correct)
Run 2: Deletes “banana,” returns “apple,” shows Index 3. (Correct)
Run 3: Deletes “apple,” returns “durian,” shows Index 1. (Correct)
Run 4: Deletes “durian,” returns “Undefined,” shows Index -1 (should return “cherry,” index 2) (Error)
Run 5: Deletes “cherry,” returns “Undefined,” shows index -1 (should be “date” at 0) (Error)                                                          With the full basket, it hits “Undefined” by the fifth loop. Not too sure why this is – any ideas?

Comment: Disregard the last: I moved the randomizing section into the main function, and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be so dense, but I am fairly new to js. I can't get any output from that at all. Here is the rewrite:

```
 <center>
 <h1> <span id="fruit"></span><p></h1> 

   <script> var fruitSound = new Audio(); 
    fruitSound.src = "boardfill.mp3"; 

    function showFruitwithSound()
    { 
    fruitSound.play(); // Play button sound now 
    showBasket()
    } 

 </script>

 <p id = "indexnum">
 <button onclick="showFruitwithSound()">Choose Fruit</button>

   </center> 
 <script>  
 var indexf = mixedBasket.indexOf(document.getElementById('fruit').innerHTML);
 document.getElementById("indexnum").innerHTML = indexf + " this is the index number."; 
 </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Fruitpicker3.js"></script>
 </body>
```